# Changing superclass variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I read this sentence in the Swift documentation provided by Apple

```
“Subclasses are only allowed to modify variable properties of superclasses during initialization.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
```

But if I run this code it works with no problems:

```
class Person{
    var name:String

    init(name:String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

class SuperHero:Person{
    var power:String?

    init(name:String, power:String?){
        self.power = power
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    func changeName (){
        // HERE I'M CHANGING A SUPERCLASS VARIABLE outside Initialization!!!
        self.name = "Mark"
    }
}

let superman = SuperHero(name: "Superman", power: "Fly!")
superman.changeName()
println("\(superman.name)")
```

Have I misinterpreted the documentation?

Comment: The sentence from The Swift Programming Language doesn't make any sense to me. Your example shows how it should works and it does. Changing values of superclass properties is key in the OOP world. Is it possible, that Apple means changing the property itself? From on type to another?

Comment: I really don't know. Changing type shouldn't be allowed at all in my opinion...

Comment: The sentence only makes sense when paired with the following one: “You can’t modify inherited constant properties of subclasses.” It's not really saying that you can only modify variables during initialization it's saying you can't modify constants during initialization of a subclass. Confusing and ambiguous I agree

Comment: @Mariusz, the quoted sentence makes perfect sense, it was just seriously misread by the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is serious misinterpretation in the quoted sentence. that is the original quote in its natural environment.

> Subclasses are only allowed to modify *variable* properties of superclasses during initialization. You can’t modify inherited constant properties of subclasses.

please read in with the correct emphasis, because that sentence means that on other words:

1. you are allowed to modify the *variables* of superclass during initilaization, but you **are not allowed** to do such thing with constants of superclass.
2. **there is no such statement here:** you are allowed to modify the *variables* only during initialization but and later you are not allowed to modify them.

I hope that makes sense now.

Comment: It makes sense! 
But it's still a confusing sentence :) your interpretation helps a lot to correctly understand it.

Comment: "Subclasses are only allowed to modify _variable_ properties of superclasses. You can’t modify inherited constant properties of subclasses." is how it should've been written.

Comment: @GoodbyeStackOverflow, I agree that is ambiguous, however grammatically it is correct because the word _"only"_ is for the word _"variable"_ not for the phrase _"during initialization"_. the English language is tricky. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sentence from [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Inheritance.html) is this:

> Subclasses are only allowed to modify *variable* properties of superclasses during initialization.

Note that "variable" word is in italics. It means that there is an *emphasis* on this word, and the resulting sentence means that during initialization you can modify only those properties of superclass that are variable.

Answer (score 0):

In expansion of my comment, the book is saying you can't do this:

```
class Person{
    let name:String

    init(name:String){
        self.name = name // This is fine, but see warnings below
    }
}

class SuperHero:Person{
    var power:String?

    init(name:String, power:String?){
        self.power = power
        super.init(name: name)  // WARNING: Cannot assign to 'name' in 'self'
    }

    func changeName (){
        // HERE I'M CHANGING A SUPERCLASS VARIABLE outside Initialization!!!
        self.name = "Mark" // WARNING: Cannot assign to 'name' in 'self'
    }
}

let superman = SuperHero(name: "Superman", power: "Fly!")
superman.changeName()
println("\(superman.name)")
```

As I commented above, the sentence only makes sense when paired with the following one: “You can’t modify inherited constant properties of subclasses.” It's not really saying that you can modify variables *only* during initialization it's saying you can't modify inherited constants during initialization of a subclass (nor at any point). The word initialization distracts from the point being made.